# Is it a good or natural way to implement data access object like this?

Tags: design-patterns

After I read Fowler's PoEAA, I'm really confused about what is a good or a natural way to design the data access layer.
I used to let a data access object return a simple java bean like:

```
public class Person {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private Gender gender;

    //... setters and getters
}
```

And the data access object is like

```
public class PersonDataAccessImpl implements PersonDataAccess {
    public Person getPersonById(long id) throws DataAccessException {
        //... select the database
    }
    public void addPerson(Person person) throws DataAccessException {
        //... insert into the database
    }
    ...
}
```

The Person object will be used throughout the whole application including the data access layer above and also web presentation layer.
But according to PoEAA, data access layer is usually at the bottom of the layers. Is it not a good way to let the DAO depend on bean objects(Person), which will be later used in domain layer, service layer and presentation layer? And how to design the domain layer since in my opinion the difference between a domain object and a simple java bean is that a simple java bean only lacks behaviors in a domain one.

Comment: What are the key questions here? It's hard to pick out what you're actually asking. Your data access class looks like the beginning of a repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's obviously no one true way to architect an application, but my own thoughts follow...

I agree that the main difference between a **plain java bean** and a **domain object** is behaviour.  But I would argue that you really should have behaviour in your domain object, other you risk an [anemic domain model](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html). Design your domain model with domain objects, not just plain objects that are bags of getters and setters.  If it's part of a domain, then it really is likely to have some associated behaviour.

It is perfectly fine for your **data access objects** to depend on domain objects such as Person - in fact I would argue that this is entirely their purpose.  I see data access as map between your relational data store and your object model.  Your brief snippet of implementation looks akin to a **repository** in fact, which is just that, a mediator between the domain and data mapping layers.

There is some argument that you should avoid using your domain objects in your presentation layer, and expose only lightweight data objects to the client for viewing.  (See for example the common idea of **view model** classes in ASP.NET MVC applications.)  Your service layer would essentially translate from domain objects to these view objects and provide them to the front-end clients.  One key argument to this is if some unknown client is going to use your service, you don't want them having full access to your domain objects and all your business logic - you just want to provide them with what they need to know to display to the user.  If you are your own and only client though this is less of an issue.

You don't always need a complex domain model of course.  You might have something more like Active Record, where the domain objects manage their own persistence.  You can also look at something such as CQRS, where you may bypass the domain model altogether for getting view information to the client, going straight from stored views of data to tailored view classes.  (A domain model is still used on the command side of things however.)

My advice:  if it's sufficiently complex, do the following:

- have a domain model of objects with behaviour
- have a data access layer that mediates between your domain model and your data store (this will depend on your domain objects)
- have a service layer that exposes the necessary operations of your application for your client to display and post back data

Comment: +1 This is a nice answer.  I am struggling a bit with the best way to adapt my data model object layer to the clients that will be using it in way way that will be maintainable, flexible, and scalable.  As I got into it, I found that it is not immediately obvious how to present (and edit) information from a highly normalized data store to client applications.  Still working at it, but the tiered approach discussed here is where my own work has been heading.